# "The buffer is accessed out of bounds" is reported by cppcheck

Tags: memset, boundary, cppcheck

The static code analysis tool cppcheck reported a severe error in the code below: I don't know what is the problem.

```
      #define NUM_UPDATE_COUNT 3
      #define MAX_NUM_CH_1LINE 27

      wchar_t m_cCnt_Buf[NUM_UPDATE_COUNT][MAX_NUM_CH_1LINE];

      Init_PushPt();

      memset((char *)&m_cCnt_Buf[1], 0x20, sizeof(m_cCnt_Buf[1])); /* Buffer is accessed out of bounds: m_cCnt_Buf */
      memset((char *)&m_cCnt_Buf[2], 0x20, sizeof(m_cCnt_Buf[2])); /* Buffer is accessed out of bounds: m_cCnt_Buf */               
      m_cCnt_Buf[1][2] = '0';
      m_cCnt_Buf[2][8] = '0';
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code above. Any ideas why these get picked up and how fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

Interesting. It looks like a FP to me. However I fail to reproduce this FP with Cppcheck.

Comment: You can report any Cppcheck-FP you see in the Cppcheck issue tracker (http://trac.cppcheck.net), fixing FP reports is high priority. A minimal code example that reproduce the FP should be included in the report.